# AS3 loading image from Array into empty movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I have tried this to load image path from database via php and load the image in flash. Now how can i add child to every single image to a every single empty movie clip for the farther use. the code is

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("m_shirts.php"));    
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _done);    
function _done(e:Event):void    {
    ldr.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _done);    
    var ar:Array = String(e.target.data).split("#"); 
    for (var x:int=0; x<ar.length; x++){
            /*var img:Loader = new Loader();
            img.load(new URLRequest(ar[x]));
            shirts.addChild(img);*/
            var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            var my_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
            myLoader.load(new URLRequest(ar[x])); 
            my_mc.addChild(myLoader); 
            addChild(my_mc);
            my_mc.x= my_mc.width + 50;          
        }                   
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is hard to understand, specifically this sentence makes little sense: "Now how can i add child to every single image to a every single empty movie clip for the farther use."

Comment: The images pulling from database where the image is shirts image. When a user click on the image it will cover the body of the avatar. So. what should i do?

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the image width?

Comment: My question should be CONVERTING THE LOADER INTO MOVIECLIP

Comment: You can't get the width of the image until it has loaded, so you'll need to listen for the complete event from the loader.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I will try to answer this from what I understand:

1. You simply cannot convert `Loader` instances to a `MovieClip`. A `Loader` is a `Loader` and a `MovieClip` is a `MovieClip`, much like an `Array` is an `Array` or a `Function` is a `Function`. Their common base class is `DisplayObjectContainer`. It has most of the functionality `MovieClips` have except for child manipulation (although the methods are there) and drawing API as per the `graphics` property.
2. You can access the size of the loaded image by reading the `Loader`'s `width` and `height`.
3. Your problem seems to be, that you want to determine the image's size **before it is loaded**. You cannot do that. You have to wait for it to load first. The `contentLoaderInfo` will dispatch an `Event.COMPLETE` when the image is available.